# How to make site use https default?

Tags: http, url, iis, https

Currently we have a site that the public can use to access and make payments. On IIS, the site is enabled for use on http and https on ports 80 and 443.

When I access the site without specifying http or https, it will default go to http, for example if I go to example.com, it goes to http://example.com.

If I remove the port 80 binding on the site, will that then make the site default to https if I access it by example.com?

Or do I need to use URL rewrite or HTTP Redirect for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that people can only use specific pages securely no matter what links they come from, it’s best to use a server-side approach to redirect the user if it’s not HTTPS. You can do that with a code snippet inserted on top of your secure page. Here’s one in PHP:

```
// Require https
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
$url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: $url");
exit;
}
```

Taken from http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-get-https-setting-up-ssl-on-your-website/